# Code debugging, Raspberry pi relays and if statements

Tags: python, raspberry-pi

I've a problem with Raspberry Pi relays. Earlier I wrote about LED's and the problem was similar, but this time these methods don't work.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import sys
import time
import datetime
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO
import SDL_DS1307

GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BCM)
GPIO.setwarnings(False)

Rele1 = 17
Rele2 = 27



GPIO.setup(17, GPIO.OUT)
GPIO.setup(27, GPIO.OUT)

filename = time.strftime("%Y-%m-%d%H:%M:%SRTCTest") + ".txt"
starttime = datetime.datetime.utcnow()

ds1307 = SDL_DS1307.SDL_DS1307(1, 0x68)
ds1307.write_now()
while True:
        currenttime = datetime.datetime.utcnow()
        deltatime = currenttime - starttime
        data=time.strftime("%Y"+"%m"+"%d"+"%H"+"%M")
        with open('data.txt') as f:
                for line in f:
                        parts=line.split()
                        if parts[0]<=(data)<=parts[1]:
                                GPIO.output(Rele1, True)
                                GPIO.output(Rele2, False)
                                break
                        else:
                                GPIO.output(Rele1, False)
                                GPIO.output(Rele2, True)
        sleep(0.10)
```

I have edited the code a little bit, now just when `if` is `True` one channel of relay module, GPIO27, is clicking very fast. I tried changing the GPIOs but the result is the same.

When `if` is `False`, then relay works as it should. If I put `break` after `else` , the code stops doing .txt file check and if there are more dates, the  program doesn't do anything

Comment: Can you explain what you are trying to do? Also what are the contents of data.txt?

Comment: Im trying to controll relays by the date, if dates in txt file are between present date, one relay turns on other off, if not one off other on.

Comment: Have you eliminated the possibility of a hardware problem by testing that the outputs drive the relay correctly using simple code to e.g. set them true for 2 seconds then false for 2seconds?  Also, the code as it stands is repeatedly and rapidly setting the outputs as fast as it can go round the loop. It would be more elegantly done to only change the relay outputs when the date actually changes, i.e. only setting the relay outputs to false or true when the value required changes. Have you tried this? (Or you could simply put a delay for a minute in the loop).

Comment: And can you post an example of the contents of data.txt? Does it have more than one line?

Comment: 201609201817 201609201817<br/>
201609201819 201609201819<br/>
201609201820 201609201830<br/>
<br/> And yes, it have more than one line.

Comment: P.S. Earlyer that code with leds was working, but in that main if was more ifs because then you can set the colours of leds, now just turn on and off, but nots working

Comment: You may not have been able to see the LEDs flickering on/off, and also maybe you only tested with data.txt where the first line was returning true, in which case your code happens to work - but when true is the result for later lines the outputs are not stable because your code turns them off/on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to do some work on your logic. Think about what happens when the the time is between the values on the third line of data.txt. As your code reads the first  line, the result is false so the outputs are set correspondingly, then on the second line the result is false and the outputs are set for false again, then the third line the result is true so the outputs are set for true. Then the file is immediately read again and the first line result is false, 2nd line false, third line true. So your relays will be set to false-false-true each time the file is read, again and again.

You need to make your code only set the outputs when ANY of the tests is true (a logical OR) and not for the result of each test.

You probably need to do something like work out the OR across all the lines of the file then after finishing the file, if the result is true or false set the outputs accordingly.

And as a tip for debugging, if you had put a simple print statement in each branch of the if statement you would have seen on the console how once one of the lines after the first line has a true result the outputs are being toggled around on every read through the file.

```
while True:
    currenttime = datetime.datetime.utcnow()
    deltatime = currenttime - starttime
    data=time.strftime("%Y"+"%m"+"%d"+"%H"+"%M")
    with open('data.txt') as f:
        result = False
        for line in f:
            parts=line.split()
            # compare the current time with the part1/part2 from data.txt
            if parts[0]<=(data)<=parts[1]:
                # The current time is between these, so our overall result is going to be True
                result = True
    # depending on the result, set the relays appropriately
    if result:
        print "Result is True"
        GPIO.output(Rele1, True)
        GPIO.output(Rele2, False)
    else:
        print "Result is False"
        GPIO.output(Rele1, False)
        GPIO.output(Rele2, True)
    # delay for a second - no point reading faster than the clock changes
    time.sleep(1)
```

`

Comment: But if understand it correctly, "break" after if should have stop file checking till the statement becomes false? If not, is that useful to at the first read the whole file and then if there is one correct line, relay opens, if not, checking file further.

Comment: Yes break forces execution out of the loop, let's say that happens on line 3 of data.txt, but what happens when the loop restarts and line 1 of data.txt is read? Add those prints, so you can actually see what is happening!

Comment: Edit my description slightly - 'you need to make your code only set the outputs for 'true' when any of the results is true, and set it to false otherwise' - noting that the otherwise decision can only be made once all of the results have been worked out.

Comment: If I have answered your question please accept this as the asnwer.